# Finding nested values in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoid, pymongo

I have a data:

```
{'_id': 0, 'values': [{'value': 1, 'value_type': 'type1'}, {'value': 2, 'value_type': 'type2'}, {'value': 134, 'value_type' : 'type1'}, {'value': 2564, 'value_type': 'type212'}]} 
{'_id': 1, 'values': [{'value': 136, 'value_type': 'type1'}, {'value': 465652, 'value_type': 'type1'}, {'value': 4, 'value_type' : 'type299'}, {'value': 112564, 'value_type': 'type2456'}]}
```

I'm working with pymongo 2.2 and Python 3.2.

The goal is to find the dictionary (value and value_type) which has `value_type` is equal to `type1` and minimal value of `value` to remove them.  In my case, that's `{'value': 1, 'value_type': 'type1'} and {'value': 136, 'value_type': 'type1'}` and I want to remove them.

How do I to achieve that?

**--Edit--**

I'm aware how to update (delete in my case), I'll be using $unset operator. What I'm unaware is how to find the values I need to remove.

Comment: @alexvassel -- "what have you tried?" is not helpful. This question has a specific answer, independent of anything the poster has tried. If you're looking for information about the solution because you don't know it, consult the documentation or your expertise. This question is about how to phrase a query. It would be like asking "what have you tried?" to someone asking "What is a working way to refer to the second building on the left in French?".

Comment: @Purrell I can not see your answer. Text that you typed will not solve the problem.

Comment: @Purrell I don't think that we should talk about this anymore. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pull/) operator like this:

```
value = 150
coll.update({}, 
    {'$pull': {'values': {'value_type': 'type1', 'value': {'$lt': value}}}},
    multi=True)
```

Setting the `multi` parameter to `True` tells the update to update all documents, not just the first one.

Comment: I don't know the value, each item has their own minimal value.

Comment: @AlanDert Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  If you need to remove the element with the minimum value, there's no set operation to do that so you'll need to iterate over the collection and manually update each item to remove that element in code.

Comment: @AlanDert See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13407073/1259510) to a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

use a $pull update query 
  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull

```
coll.update({}, {"$pull" :{"values": {"value":1}})
```